# Automatically copying all rows written in a given input field, pasting them in another browser element

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

Say I visit a certain webpage that has a form with an input field and I want every row typed into this input field to be saved in the same browser element, like some div, after I hit "Return" in the form. For example:

[image]

I would want it to be saved in real time, without the need to submit the form, that is, the (orange-background) note should "listen" to any row of in the form and copy it after I pressed return.

I can create the note this way:

Style:

```
.note {position: fixed; bottom: 0; right: 0; width: 500px; height: 500px; background: orange}
```

Behavior:

```
let x = document.createElement('div');
x.class.classList.add('note');
```

I can also select the input field I want to listen to, like this:

```
document.querySelector('.myInputField');
```

But how could I make sure any row of text written in the input field, is actually copied to the note after hitting Return, in real time?

I need the note's content not to be deleted if I mistakenly refresh the webpage.

### Update for snapjs:

I tried to use this code to copy text from the input field to the div in each "Return" press inside the input field, but it doesn't work:

```
myInputField.addEventListener('keydown', (k)=>{
    if ( keyCode == 13 ) {
        myInputField.textDocument = myNote.textDocument;
    }
});
```

(At first I used identicality as with `===` but saw I need an assignment like `=`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my recommendation:

1. Add an "input" event listener to the textarea to handle any changes to the textarea.  Within this event listener, you can add the data to your "orange box"
2. Look into localStorage to persist the data in case the window is closed

**update**

Good try, but keyCode is actually a property of k and can be accessed this way.  Also, if I understand correctly, I think you want to set the innerHTML of the note to the value of the input field.

```
myInputField.addEventListener('keydown', (k)=>{
    if ( k.keyCode == 13 ) {
        myNote.innerHTML = myInputField.value;
    }
});
```

Comment: But how will you add the data to the Orangebox? How can you copy "in real time" in JS?

Comment: If the orange box is a div, for example, you can set the "innerHTML" of the div to the value of the textarea.

Comment: Hmm, based on your suggestion I tried the following code but didn't work. Please see update in question.

Comment: @OsiOs see if my updated response helps get you there

Comment: Originally I used `k.` before `keyCode` I just forgot it in this case. Sorry for that mistake. Also, sorry for writing `textDocument` instead of `textContent` (I tend to confuse those for some reason but as I'm very new to JS, I hope with time I'll less confuse them). Anyway, seems I really had to add the `value` (it solved the problem). So thank you and I've learned a lot.